# Php Larvel Views Issue

Tags: php, laravel

I have create a orders page in my POS web software based on PHP larvel 8 but, when I am trying to add another column with table number it keeps stucked in processing and  two rows appear in the orders page.
I just want another column with the order numbers.

[Here is the screenshot about the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ee0n3.png)

```
@extends('layouts.layout')
@section("content")
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        
        <div class="d-flex flex-wrap mb-4">
            <div class="mr-auto">
                <span class="text-title">{{ __("POS Orders") }}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="">
                @if (check_access(array('A_ADD_ORDER'), true))
                    <a href="{{ route('add_order')}}" role="button" class="btn btn-primary">{{ __("New Order") }}</a>
                @endif
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table id="listing-table" class="table display nowrap w-100">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>{{ __("Order Number") }}</th>
                        <th>{{ __("Customer Phone") }}</th>
                        <th>{{ __("Table Number") }}</th>

                        <th>{{ __("Customer Email") }}</th>
                        <th>{{ __("Amount") }}</th>
                        <th>{{ __("Status") }}</th>
                        <th>{{ __("Created On") }}</th>
                        <th>{{ __("Updated On") }}</th>
                        <th>{{ __("Created By") }}</th>
                        <th>{{ __("Action") }}</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
@endsection

@push('scripts')
    <script src="{{ asset('plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/datatable.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/pages/orders.js') }}"></script>
    <script>
    'use strict';
        var orders = new Orders();
        orders.load_listing_table();
    </script>
@endpush
```

Comment: code from `Orders@load_listing_table()` !? debugg the `orders` var. is correct?

Comment: Could you please add your datatable.js code?